# Informação em várias tabelas ou apenas em uma?

Tags: mysql, sql, table, view

Tenho muita informação que preciso de guardar na base de dados.
Alguma dessa informação é algo muito idêntica:

Exemplo: hora1, hora2, hora3, ... hora10.

A minha dúvida é se devo guardar tudo na mesma tabela ou criar uma tabela para a informação e outra específica para guardar as horas, colocando uma foreign key da primeira tabela na tabela das horas.

Posteriormente criar uma vista com tudo.

O que será melhor?

Answer (score 1):

Cria uma outra tabela para cadastrar as horas, já que pode se levar em conta que a quantidade de campos seria hora1 .. horaN, assim se num futuro você precisar criar outra "hora" será só adicionar uma linha..

E criar outra outra tabela fazendo a relação entre sua tabela a tabela de horas.

Por exemplo

```
Tabela nome

Id |  Nome
01 | XXXXXX
02 | YYYYYY
03 | WWWWWW

Tabela horas

Id |  Hora
01 | Hora1
02 | Hora2
03 | Hora3


Tabela Relacao NomeHoras

Id | IdNome | IdHora | Valor
01 |   01   |   01   | '00:00'
02 |   01   |   02   | '01:00'
03 |   01   |   03   | '02:00'
04 |   02   |   01   | '03:00'
05 |   03   |   01   | '04:00'
```

Espero ter ajudado!